# Missing headers on POST request with python requests

Tags: python, http, http-post, python-requests

I'm currently using the python requests module to perform automated HTTP tasks on a website.
The problem is that I don't get the same results on my console as on my browser.

This is what I get when making a POST request on my browser:

[image]

This is what I get when making the POST request through the python requests module and running the `.headers` method on the request:

```
    {
      'Date': 'Fri, 14 Jul 2017 15:19:22 GMT',
      'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
      'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
      'Connection': 'keep-alive',
      'Cache-Control': 'private',
      'Location': '/cart/view',
      'Set-Cookie': 'png.notice=9Hz8GWQ38JQZqTrqcsnn1J5nfgIZt71orHtf71mI+rwqFpQg4RnV7BqZni/GgIS/SmUnC4jgnhjQuDhZNW2adxeLctG+bToT0wTTbgxe40t5RmbVv1viuH2gkL1eH2xN3IavOUBhVXm+JlQrmVnHLocqjgvWi8wAClLYmrShY1U2ege9; expires=Fri, 14-Jul-2017 15:34:03 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly',
      'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET',
      'X-UA-Compatible': 'IE=Edge,chrome=1',
      'Server': 'cloudflare-nginx',
      'CF-RAY': '37e575befbf43c35-CDG'
    }
```

Notice how the two results are completely different.
I'm trying to get the "Location" header inside the Response headers (the one beginning with "https://live.adyen.com/hpp...".
What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: This is my source code:

```
    request = session.post('https://www.nakedcph.com/cart/process', data=user_info)
    request.url
    # outputs 'https://www.nakedcph.com/cart/view' (probably the issue)
    request.headers
    # outputs the headers (but not all of them?)
```

PS: After making the POST request, the website redirects to the URL inside the "Location" header from the Response headers.

[image]

Comment: How are you making the request through python? What does your code look like? The headers you pass via python are _not_ the same as your browser's headers. This is an important detail.

Comment: Just added my source code. What I don't understand is what kind of headers the requests module is outputting. Is it the Response headers or the Request headers?

Comment: Request headers. Try `session.post('https://www.nakedcph.com/cart/process', headers={'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}, data=user_info)`

Comment: It's outputting the same headers. My guess is that it's printing out the headers of request.url which is different than the url I used to make the POST with.

Comment: It seems that the website is redirecting to another url after making the POST.

Comment: And how do I access the response headers? Because I actually want only to get access to the "Location" header inside the Response headers.

Comment: My bad. It is the response headers.

Comment: Does the redirect happen on the browser too? You can set allow_redirects=True when making the post call.

Comment: No the website doesn't redirect on the browser. It actually makes a get request to the URL inside the "Location" header from the Response headers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149241/discussion-between-viktor-ronnow-and-cs).

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Missed some parameters in the post request. My bad.